# How to pass arguments to functions while executing a python script from terminal?

Tags: command-line, python, functions

I have a python file named `solution.py` and I can successfully execute it through the terminal using the following commands:

```
chmod +x solution.py
python3 solution.py
```

This works just fine if I have simple print phrases and so on.

What should I do if I have defined a function in `solution.py` and I want to call it with parameters that I want directly from terminal? How do I pass the arguments to the function call?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15747198/1123893

Comment: You do not need here `chmod +x`! Just read access.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use the [`sys`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#module-sys) module. Here is an example :

```
import sys

first_arg = sys.argv[1]
second_arg = sys.argv[2]

def greetings(word1=first_arg, word2=second_arg):
    print("{} {}".format(word1, word2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    greetings()
    greetings("Bonjour", "monde")
```

It has the behavior your are looking for :

```
$ python parse_args.py Hello world
Hello world
Bonjour monde
```

Comment: ok, but how many of args we can send from terminal to the file?

Answer (score 2):

Python provides more than one way to parse arguments. The best choice is using the [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module, which has many features you can use.

So you have to parse arguments in your code and try to catch and fetch the arguments inside your code.

You can't just pass arguments through terminal without parsing them from your code.